# A characterization of pure sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves, moduli-space

I have started reading the book "The Geometry of moduli of sheaves" by Huybrechts and Lehn.
This is a statement in this book at page no.3 the last line.

"$E$ is pure if and only if all associated points of $E$ have the same dimension."
Definition for associated points of a sheaf is as follows:

$Ass(E) = \{x \in X \vert m_x \in AssE_x \}$.

Point has always dimension 0 ,So my question is, what does this mean by saying that associated points have same dimension?

Does this mean that local rings $O_x$ has the same dimension for all $x$ associated point of $E$ ?

Can anyone suggest me a good reference which supports me while studying this book?

Comment: In scheme-theoretic algebraic geometry, the dimension of a point is not always $0$...

Comment: @Tabes Bridges Where can i find an example of this?

Comment: With the dimension of a point, they mean the dimension of its closure. For instance for an integral scheme the dimension of the generic point is equal to the dimension of the scheme.

Comment: @MooS can you provide me proof of this?

Comment: A proof of what? I just clarified the definition.

Comment: @MooS I want proof of  "E is pure if and only if all associated points of E have the same dimension."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a P.hd. thesis by Alain Leytem entitled with "Torsion and purity on non-integral schemes and singular sheaves in the fine Simpson moduli spaces of one-dimensional sheaves on the projective plane ".The above asked question is answered there and give a good exposition to the relation between torsion sheave and purity of coherent sheaves over Noetherian scheme. Link is given below:
http://orbilu.uni.lu/handle/10993/23380

Comment: I think the treatment given in the thesis is not so correct. The author claims on page 113, several lines before Theorem 3.1.31 that the O_X-module constructed restricts to the sheafification of a certain module. However, I don't think this is true, at least needs to be clarified: Let us assume X is affine. On a basic open subset $D(f)$, the sections are of the form $s/f^n$ where $s$ is a global section, but this is not so clear for me. The support of $s$ could be so large which restricts to one with dimension $\leq d$ in $D(f)$.